# How to find grep string in file; manipulate; then write to new file?

Tags: macos, command-line, grep

```
    for file in *.doc; do grep '/[A-Z\.]{225}/' $file > $file.txt;  done;
```

In a directory of files, each file has a string of 225 characters (all uppercase letters periodically separated by dots "."; dots are intermittent: anywhere between 3 and 15 letters apart). I need to extract this string and present it as a 15x15 grid of data.

I am trying find the string, add carriage return every 15 characters, then copy new string to a new file; or concatenate all 15x15 grids onto one file.

I am not understanding something about the grep string, as even attempts to find the string in a single file have not yielded successful results.

```
    grep '/[A-Z\.]{225}/' file332.doc > file332.txt;
```

Sample input string X = A-Z:

XXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX..XXXXXX..XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.XXXX...XXXXX..XXX.XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXX.XXX..XXXXX...XXXX.XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXX..XXXXXX..XXX.XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXXXXX.XXXXX.XXXXX

Desired output:

```
    XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX
    XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX
    XXXXXXXXXXX.XXX
    ..XXXXXX..XXXXX
    XXXX.XXXXXXXXXX
    XXX.XXX.XXXX...
    XXXXX..XXX.XXX.
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    .XXX.XXX..XXXXX
    ...XXXX.XXX.XXX
    XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX
    XXXXX..XXXXXX..
    XXX.XXXXXXXXXXX
    XXX.XXXXX.XXXXX
    XXX.XXXXX.XXXXX
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Assuming the `dots` are every 16 chars apart, you can just convert all dots to new lines using the `tr` (transliterate) cmd, i.e. `tr '.' '\012' < "$file".doc > "$file".txt` Does that get you closer to what you need? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, the dots are intermittent. anywhere between 3 and 15 spaces between letter.

Comment: Please add sample **input and** your desired **output** for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I just added it. Thanks.

Comment: If you posted a ~20 char string with a requirement to get a 4x4 array, wouldn't that show you the correct approach? As is, `XXXXX.XXXx....` is very generic and doesn't give readers much to work with. What would be the rules for turning your sample string into a 15x15. Just eliminate the dots, count each 15 and then add a new line? Good luck.

Comment: I need the dots to remain in place. They are placeholders between each word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

```
grep -Eo '[A-Z\.]{225}' file332.doc | fold -b -w 15 > file332.txt
```

Output to file332.txt:

```
XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX
XXXXX.XXXXX.XXX
XXXXXXXXXXX.XXX
..XXXXXX..XXXXX
XXXX.XXXXXXXXXX
XXX.XXX.XXXX...
XXXXX..XXX.XXX.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.XXX.XXX..XXXXX
...XXXX.XXX.XXX
XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX
XXXXX..XXXXXX..
XXX.XXXXXXXXXXX
XXX.XXXXX.XXXXX
XXX.XXXXX.XXXXX
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know why, but when I try it, the output file is zero bytes. The grep did not seem to find the string. Before coming to this forum, I had been trying similar grep strings, with the same result.

Comment: I am on a Mac, might that have something to do with it?

Comment: Try to replace `grep -Eo` by `egrep`.

Comment: I think I found part of the problem. Each file has some special characters in them. I think they are causing the grep to abort. Will need to eliminate those characters, and the your suggestion works perfectly.